# How to load/import css and assets files before the view loads (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I need to load the stylesheet and the files inside the assets folder (icon, images...) before the view loads.

My current problem is that while reloading my app, the images appear after the view by a few milliseconds.

Is there a way to fix that, with angular?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197601/how-to-load-images-before-showing-an-angular-website?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but with Server Side Rendering because when you load the app (Client side rendering) at that time the javascript find the resources to load